# How to sort Multi-dimensional array by using key With date using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have array like, and I need to sort array by date using array key
In the first key of array is userid and under this array some left and right  values related to date but I have problem in shorting array by date asc order

```
Array(
[7074471] => Array
    (
        [2017-12-16] => Array
            (
                [Left] => 5
            )

        [2017-12-20] => Array
            (
                [Left] => 2
                [Right] => 2
            )

        [2017-12-21] => Array
            (
                [Left] => 1
            )

        [2017-12-23] => Array
            (
                [Left] => 4
                [Right] => 1
            )

        [2017-12-17] => Array
            (
                [Right] => 0
            )

        [2017-12-19] => Array
            (
                [Right] => 3
            )

    )
}
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: If have inbuilt function in php so please help me

Comment: Did you try using `ksort()` and `krsort()`?

Comment: Yes but not getting responce

Comment: Because `ksort()` modifies the given array and returns boolean. Check the array after calling `ksort()`

Comment: when i try ksort() and krsort() its return 1

Comment: but i Need array with sorted by date so please help me how to possible

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php read return values.... most of the sorting functions just have to be called on the array and don't return the array. so you would take your `$array = array('1','2','3'); ksort($array); return $array;` ... get it?